# duda VBA datepicker

Tags: vba

He consumido varias horas en este tema sin respuesta por el momento.

¿cómo insertar un datepicker en formulario vba office 365?

He buscado un información sin éxito, esto al parecer se puede en versiones 2010 y 32bits.
Necesito ese control o uno similar.

Algún héroe con capa que me ayude en este tema?

Answer (score 0):

Yo utilizo en mis formularios un control de calendario que encontré googleando hace tiempo. Es bastante personalizable y funciona en 32 y 64 bits:

https://sites.google.com/site/e90e50/calendar-control-class

Lee bien las indicaciones y móntalo como indican. No tendrás problema.